# Does Azure Cosmos db Emulator require internet connection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-emulator

Azure Cosmos db Emulator will not launch when my external internet connection is offline.  Is this normal with the current emulator?

Comment: Any progress now?

Comment: Last time it occurred there were Multiple processes running.  After killing all of them I was able to restart.   Currently seems to be working w/o the internet connection.

Comment: So, i think it's result of port conflict which mentioned in my answer. You could mark the below answer for others' reference on the forum.Thanks.

Comment: Any updates now?

Comment: What appears to happen is that the Emulator crashes and does not release  port 8081 thus blocking any restarts.  I just need time to develop a non-reboot method to clear the port on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cosmos DB Emulator simulates a service locally and it is supposed that the external network offline does not affect the emulator 's operation.

You could check the points as below to troubleshoot your issue.

Point 1: Try to ping your localhost.

Point 2: Try to telnet the cosmos db local server port.

Point 3: Check to see if the local 8081 port is occupied causing a port conflict. The emulator didn't start at all.

Point 4: Check the `hosts` configuration file to see if the local IP port is pointing to another domain.

Point 5 : Check the firewall for any restrictions.